# Sending user input to console in Java

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

I am trying to write something in Java to automatically import a certificate.  When entering this command in the command shell:

```
    keytool -import -keystore c:\.truststore -alias xenv -file cacert.pem
```

it asks me for 2 questions: the password and if I want to confirm.  In Python, I can use subprocess.Popen as follows:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("keytool","-import","-keystore","c:\\.truststore","-alias","xenv","-file","cacert.pem", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate("password\n" + "y\n")
```

I am now attempting to do something similar in Java.  I think I'm on the right track after a few hours of playing around, but I can't quite get it to work.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

```
import java.io.*;

public class PropertyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "keytool", "-import", "-keystore", "c:\\.truststore", "-alias", "xenv", "-file", "c:\\cacert.pem");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = pb.start();
        OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();
        out.write("password\n".getBytes());
        out.write("y\n".getBytes());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? You can provide the password as a parameter, and you can eliminate the confirmation prompt with another parameter. And you can eliminate the whole thing by using the KeyStore class.

Comment: In this simplified example you can pass in the password as a parameter, but there are a bunch of cases when using keytool or openssl that you must confirm things such as the organizational unit, etc. and you cannot pass those confirmations in as a parameter.

Comment: That is simply untrue. You can pass in *everything* as a parameter to the keytool, and you can also use the KeyStore API directly and avoid the whole problem. You're going about this quite the wrong way.

Comment: Ok, forget the keytool example.  The question is on how to pass in user input in general using a similar manner to C and Python's pOpen.  Do you know how?

Answer (score 1):

This worked.  I changed it to a BufferedWriter and flushed and closed it when I was done.  Hopefully this helps someone else out who is stuck on a similar problem!

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "keytool", "-import", "-keystore", "c:\\.truststore", "-alias", "alias", "-file", "c:\\cacert.pem");
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
    out.write("allgoodthings\n");
    out.write("y\n");
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```

Comment: You don't really need the BufferedWriter. The close may have helped, the flush almost certainly.

Comment: You're right.  I just tested with an OutputStream and it worked too.  Removing the flush actually did nothing though (nothing visible at least), but it will not work without the close.